# Keyboard and TouchPad not working after boot

Tags: libinput

I had a problem with my mouse suddenly started lagging in Ubuntu 18.10. I uninstalled libinput and restarted with the purpose of installing it again. However, after I login my mouse AND keyboard doesn't work. Not even an external USB keyboard will work. How can I install lipinput again when I can't use any mouse or keyboard?

**Edit**: I can use both the mouse and keyboard right up until I login to my user.

Regards Mikkel

Answer (score 1):

**Figured it out**: I logged in via console (CTRL + ALT + F1) and then I could login and re-install libinput.